# iOS 8 - Private API - Automatically Answer incoming call

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, iphone-6, core-telephony

For our enterprise app, we were using `CTCallAnswer(call);` private API from the CoreTelephony Framework as follows:

```
if ([str1 isEqualToString:@"kCTCallIdentificationChangeNotification"]){
    NSDictionary *info = (__bridge NSDictionary *)userInfo;
    CTCall2 *call = (__bridge CTCall *)[info objectForKey:@"kCTCall"];
    NSString *caller = CTCallCopyAddress(NULL, call);

    NSLog(@"Caller %@",caller);

    // answer this call
   CTCallAnswer(call);
}
```

But it stopped working once we upgraded to iOS 8.

Is there a way to make it work for iOS 8?